# unresolved host / Upgrade 12 to 14 Ubuntu/ Net Connection fine through browser

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, command-line, dns, ping

I recently upgraded to 'Trusty' i.e. Ubuntu 14.04. I tried pinging google.com through the terminal.

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

to remove and reinstall the resolv config, but to no avail.

Then I found the official bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1308378 I tried to do the following as instructed there:

```
cd /etc
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

But it gave an error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./resolv.conf’: File exists
```

Internet works fine through my firefox browser. In fact, I'm writing this question through the same system.

I set additional DNS servers in the WiFi settings to the google DNS servers:

```
8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

But to no avail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meybe is solution for you to change way how to resolve names.
Try following

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the `dns=dnsmasq`

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
 [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:22:64:4E:6F:70,

[ifupdown]
managed=fals
```

and restart the NM service

`sudo restart network-manager`

With this `/etc/resolv.conf` is no longer dependant on resolvconf package and is updated based on the DNS entries of each connection in the Network Manager

Also you can add `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you not set `dns` in NM per connection this will be used

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I did all that you said. No progress. ping google.com still gives the same 'unknown host' result.

Comment: Please try `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Hey, it worked! Maybe it worked after I restarted my computer! Thanks. :)